# How to copy std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<T>> to std::list<T>

Tags: c++, boost, vector

```
std::list<KinBody::Link::Geometry> geometries = link->GetGeometries();
```

The type of `link->GetGeometries()` is `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Geometry>>`
and I got the following error with the above code.

```
error: conversion from ‘const std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<OpenRAVE::KinBody::Link::Geometry> >’ to     non-scalar type ‘std::list<OpenRAVE::KinBody::Link::Geometry>’ requested
std::list<KinBody::Link::Geometry> geometries = link->GetGeometries();
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Try ```const auto& vec = link->GetGeometries();
std::list<KinBody::Link::Geometry> geometries(vec.begin(), vec.end());``` ?

Comment: Use `std::transform`.. or use range-based `for` loop and do the conversion manually on *per-item* basis.

Comment: I tried your answer, I got this error: `error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘vec’ with no type [-fpermissive]
  const auto& vec = link->GetGeometries();`

Comment: @Johnnylin `auto` is a C++11 feature, make sure that's turned on.

Comment: try replace `auto` with explict type `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<OpenRAVE::KinBody::Link::Geometry> >`

Comment: @Rafael: This question has absolutely nothing to do with OpenRAVE. Please do not tagspam.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
std::list<KinBody::Link::Geometry> geometries;

for (auto const & p : link->GetGeometries())
    geometries.push_back(*p);
```

For the `for (auto const & p : ...)` part you need C++11 support enabled (it uses automatic type deduction and range-based for loop).

Pre-C++11 equivalent is

```
std::list<KinBody::Link::Geometry> geometries;

typedef std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<KinBody::Link::Geometry>> geometries_vector_t;

geometries_vector_t const & g = link->GetGeometries();

for (geometries_vector_t::const_iterator i = g.begin(); i != g.end(); ++i)
    geometries.push_back(**i); // dereferencing twice: once for iterator, once for pointer
```

NB: all this looks very unnatural. Objects being returned as shared pointers means that `KinBody::Link::Geometry` is actually a base class or interface, or that objects of this type are large and the interface is designed to avoid heavy copying, or something else. I advise not to copy the objects and store them as shared pointers as the interface suggests, unless you actually know you need the copies.

Comment: Not only "*auto const & part*", for the `for( : )` as well, you need C++11.

Comment: If not using C++ 11, then this code should work right : `std::list<KinBody::Link::Geometry> geometries;
 for (std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<KinBody::Link::Geometry> > ::iterator it=link->GetGeometries().begin(); 
  it != link->GetGeometries().end(); ++it){
  geometries.push_back(*it);
 }`

Comment: @Johnnylin added version without c++11

Comment: @Johnnylin your code won't work, you should do `**it`, see my answer.

Comment: @MarcGlisse `std::list` has no `reserve` method

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned boost, let me show you some Boost Range sugar.

```
link->getgeometries() | adaptors::indirected
```

this will result in a range that contains the `Geometry&` elements. Fill the list with `copy_range`:

```
geometries = boost::copy_range<std::list<link::geometry>>(
        link->getgeometries() | adaptors::indirected
    );
```

See a fully working demo:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd2108db1d1d32c3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace KinBody {

    struct Link {
        struct Geometry {};

        std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Geometry> > GetGeometries() const {
            return {};
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    using namespace boost;
    using namespace KinBody;

    auto link = make_shared<Link>();
    auto geometries = boost::copy_range<std::list<Link::Geometry>>(
            link->GetGeometries() | adaptors::indirected
        );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The line

```
std::list<KinBody::Link::Geometry> geometries = link->GetGeometries();
```

tries to assign a vector to a list. The compiler tells you that you cannot do that. What you have to do is iterate the vector and insert each element to the list.

Note that the vector contains shared pointers to geometries whereas the list is declared to contain instances. If you want to store a pointer in the list you have to declare it as:

```
std::list<KinBody::Link::Geometry*>  // note the *
```